# IBM MQ Drops Messages if there is no Listener

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

I am trying to run a IBM MQ in a Docker container and it mostly works. However it seems like the messages are dropped if there is no listener pending.

I can not find where it is configured how many messages should be held by the message.

This is my mqs.ini:

```
AllQueueManagers:
   #********************************************************************#
   #* The path to the qmgrs directory, below which queue manager data  *#
   #* is stored                                                        *#
   #********************************************************************#
   DefaultPrefix=/var/mqm

LogDefaults:
   LogDefaultPath=/var/mqm/log

QueueManager:
   Name=QM1
   Prefix=/var/mqm
   Directory=QM1
   InstallationName=Installation1
DefaultQueueManager:
   Name=QM1
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: When you say dropped what do you mean? They don't appear on the Queue at all, they go to the dead letter Queue?
Also what do you mean by no listener pending? 

Running a Queue Manager in a docker container is similar to running it on any machine, it still needs all of the basic things you would need to connect an application to it and put a message to a Queue.

Comment: Looking at the title of your question, If there is no listener running on the Queue Manager in the container then you will not be able to connect a client application into the Queue Manager at all. You need to create and start the listener on the Queue Manager with a port that has been exposed by the Dockerfile or when you created the container.

Answer (score 0):

This was a misunderstanding on my side.

The Queue did work correctly, there was another process pulling the messages. That's why the messages were gone if you did not have the listener queued up.